# Some FontAwesome icons are not appearing

Tags: font-awesome

Some of the FontAwesome icons are not appearing for some reason when I host them on a server, but appear when I view them on my localhost. I've been looking at HTML on the host address using Google Chrome's inspect element feature - there appears to be an empty style tag in the header section that does not exist on the actual index.html:

[image: mysterious style]

If I do delete that code in the Inspect Element feature, the FontAwesome icons appear!

http://lanceperalta.x10host.com/ - Here is the website. (Please excuse the content!)

Comment: Lance it's better if you build a smaller example where that issue is visible, i tried to check it out but it was hard to understand what is missing :)

Comment: What about that `styleswitch.js`? Could be that this library adds stuff to the page and that the empty style is the result of this under some conditions?

Comment: @uraimo , I believe that this only switches the stylesheet, but I do not understand why the facebook icon is still there.

Comment: Oh, now i see what you meant, deleting the style , the twitter&co icons appear...

Comment: There is a lot of stuff in this page, i recommend to remove one piece at a time until you notice it starts working as expected (no empty tag, icons ok)

Comment: @uraimo , The icons do appear, but only when I view it through file:/// .

Comment: Then it is probably due to some paths to resources being incorrect.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf , Hey, thanks for replying, I'll double check everything just in case. Thank you.

Comment: Open your site in Firefox and open the web console in Tools/Web Developer menu. The messages I saw helped me debug my FA problem.

Comment: @koan , Hey, thanks for replying. The icons appear normally on Firefox, but not on Google Chrome. The error messages I get on there is just security errors about certificates.